# Two finite fields are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F = \Bbb{Z}_2$.  Given the irreducible polynomials $f(x)= x^3 + x + 1$, and $g(y) = y^3 + y^2 + 1$, form the fields $K = F[x]/(f(x))$ and $E = F[y] / (g(y))$.  These are fields of order 8 (given), so they must be isomorphic.  Is the map $[x] \mapsto [y + 1]$ an isomorphism? It's clearly onto, and and it's one-one since $F$ and $E$ both have 8 elements.

Comment: If it is bijective, all you must do is show that it is a homomorphism, as a field isomorphism is just a bijective homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Take the $F$-isomorphism $\varphi:F[X]\to F[Y]$ which sends $X$ to $Y+1$. Then $\varphi(f)=g$ and therefore $F[X]/(f)\simeq F[Y]/(g)$.

Comment: Is your last step a consequence of some isomorphism theorem?

Comment: As a general note this method won't always work. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303763/lifting-isomorphisms-of-fields-to-automorphisms-of-polynomial-rings) for more details.

Comment: @JSchlather Actually I don't get your comment. That problem you pointed out deals with the converse of the present question. This one is generally valid: if $\varphi$ is an $F$-automorphism of $F[X]$, $f\in F[X]$ an irreducible polynomial and $g=\varphi(f)$ then $F[X]/(f)\simeq F[X]/(g)$.

Comment: @YACP I'm saying that if you know $F[X]/(f) \cong F[X]/(g)$ you can't always find an $F$-isomorphism $\varphi$ of $F[x]$ such that $\varphi(f)=g$. I was trying to say that in regards to showing two such fields were isomorphic, you couldn't always find an $F$-isomorphism. Not that an $F$-isomorphism didn't descend to an isomorphism of fields. I agree that the phrasing was unclear, sorry.

Comment: @JSchlather This question can be used in some sense to give a very simple counter-example to yours. There are (obviously) only two $F$-automorphisms of $F[X]$: $X\mapsto X$ or $X\mapsto X+1$. Now take $f=X^4+X+1$ and $g=X^4+X^2+1$. (I hope I've understood correctly your question.)

Comment: @YACP Yes. And actually I had been wondering  looking at that question again if you could find one where the polynomials weren't associate after an automorphism was applied to one. Which that example shows you can do as well.

Answer (score 0):

An element of $K$ has a unique representation as $p + (f)$, where $\deg p \leq 2$ and an element of $E$ has a unique representation as $q + (g)$, where $\deg q\leq 2$. Take $A = ax^2 + bx + c + (f)$, $B = a'x^2 + b'x + c + (f)$.
\begin{align*}
\phi(A + B) &= \phi(ax^2 + bx + c + (f) + a'x^2 + b'x + c + (f))\\
&= \phi((a + a')x^2 + (b + b')x + c + c' + (f))\\
&= (a + a')(y + 1)^2 + (b + b')(y + 1) + c + c' + (g)\\
&= (ay^2 + a + by + b + c + (g)) + (a'y^2 + a' + b'y + b' + c' + (g))\\
&= \phi(A) + \phi(B)
\end{align*}
Then if you can show $\phi(AB) = \phi(A)\phi(B)$ using a similar calculation, $\phi$ is a bijective homomorphism, and hence an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ g(x)\, =\, x^3 f(1/x)   $

**Remark** $\ $ If $\rm\:f(x)\:$ has degree $\rm\,n,\:$ then $\rm\: x^n f(1/x)\:$ is the [reciprocal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) of $\rm\:x\:,\:$ so-named because its roots are reciprocals of the roots of $\rm\:f.\:$ As here, it is easily recognizable since it coefficients are the *reverse* of that of $\rm\:f.\:$