# When are the 2 fields isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field. Let $F[x]$ be the polynomial ring and $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be 2 irreducible polynomials of same degree in $F[x]$. When do we have the 2 fields $$F[x]/<f(x)> \cong F[x]/<g(x)>$$

Well, I can think of $F[x]/<f(x)>$ as the field $F(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the root of $f(x)$ and check if any algebraic combination of $\alpha$ with elements of $F$ is a root of $g(x)$. If it is then both the fields are the same/isomorphic. But is there any general condition on the 2 polynomials such that the isomorphism holds?

Comment: Small comment (which might not even be totally correct), but I think in the quadratic case $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, the field $F[x]/(f)$ obtained only depends up to isomorphism on the discriminant, $\Delta = b^2-4ac$ (roughly because once $\sqrt{\Delta}$ is adjoined, you have everything).

Comment: If $F$ is a finite field then it is true for any polynomials ! So, No $F$ is not a finite field.

Comment: Strongly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831305